# Index/Match/Large Multiple Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, large-data

Trying to derive the top 3 highest cost fruits and return the date they were bought excluding apples and oranges. I would like to avoid using a helper column. Having issues w/ these formulas. Not sure if you can have an array (Large w/ IFS) inside of another formula. The formulas I have so far:

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(IFS(B:B,"<>Apple",B:B,"<>Orange"),1),C:C,0))`

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(IFS(B:B,"<>Apple",B:B,"<>Orange"),2),C:C,0))`

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(IFS(B:B,"<>Apple",B:B,"<>Orange"),3),C:C,0))`

[image]

Comment: Your IFS are incorrect.  IFS is pair bound, the first of each pair is the condition and the second is what to do if that condition is true.  You are treating it like countifs which it is not even remotely like.

Comment: If you have it, use FILTER and SORT and TAKE to return the correct values. `=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A:C,(B:B<>"Apple")*(B:B<>"Orange")),3,-1),3)`

Comment: You can use `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` if you dont have access to `FILTER()` `SORT()` & `TAKE()`

Comment: I do not have access to `FILTER()` `SORT()` & `TAKE()` as I am using excel 2019. I got this formula to work and do what I need it to do however I would like to retrieve the top 3 costs not just the max cost. `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,"<>Apple",B:B,"<>Orange"),C:C,0))`

Comment: That will return false positives if any of `Apple` and/or `Orange` has the same value in C as the max and is located higher than those that are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With older versions we need to use Nested Aggregates:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A2:A12)/((C2:C12=AGGREGATE(14,7,C2:C12/((B2:B12<>"A")*(B2:B12<>"O")),ROW($ZZ1)))*(B2:B12<>"A")*(B2:B12<>"O")),1))
```

Put that in the first output cell and copy/drag it down.

[image]

with Office 365 we can use TAKE/SORT/FILTER:

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A:C,(B:B<>"A")*(B:B<>"O")),3,-1),3,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works great. Amazing how the Take/SORT/FILTER is much cleaner. Might have to upgrade my excel. Thank you